# Parse, one app with two client apps and two types of users

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have one Parse app with two client apps and two types of users (sellers and users). In user class, I differentiate them by a column "type" that may be seller or user.

How can I prevent a user logs into the app seller and vice versa?

My code (standard):

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_emailTextField.text password:_passwordTextField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //...login ok
    }
    if (error) {
        //...login error
    }
}];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in one of two ways.

1. After the user logs in, check the type of the user and if they are not the correct type, log them out immediately.
2. The other way is to check the type of the user after they enter their email address. To do that will require running a Parse query to get the user type for the given email address. Then if they are the correct type, you can make the call to log them in.